# how to make an array list for each value in another array list in android studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I want to create an app that counts my expenses. I created array list for trips and now I want to create array list for categories and another array list for each category. for example, in trip1 I have 3 categories: a, b, c. and in every category, I have my expenses. so how I make an array list for each value in the trip array list?

Comment: please be more clear about the content of your lists... could you give an example ?

Comment: I want an array list for all my trips and array list for the categories and array list for the expenses. for example, I eat an apple and the apple cost for me 10$ so I want to add to the categories food and to the expenses apple, 10. I need categories and expenses array list for each trip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a database-like structure. Here are somes tips :

1) You don't want to have duplicate data, because it's so easy to introduce inconsistencies in your structure.
This means : don't add your expanses in both `expanses` list and `categories[cat]` list

2) Maybe, use some [Maps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

3) Use some classes, to aggregate data

I would have done this like this :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Trip {

    /** An item in the expanses list */
    static class Item {
        final String item;
        final int cost;
        public Item(String item, int cost) {
            this.item = item;
            this.cost = cost;
        }
        @Override public String toString() {
            return this.item + " (" + this.cost + "$)";
        }
    }

    /** A map with category as key and the associed list of items as value */
    Map<String,List<Item>> expanses;


    public Trip() {
        this.expanses = new HashMap<String,List<Item>>();
        String[] categories = {"food","clothes","souvenir"};
        for (String cat: categories) { // init the categories with empty lists
            this.expanses.put(cat, new ArrayList<Item>());
        }
    }



    /** Register a new expanse to the trip. */
    public void add(String item, int cost, String category) {
        List<Item> list = this.expanses.get(category);
        if (list == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Category '"+category+"' does not exist.");
        list.add( new Item(item, cost) );
    }

    /** Get the expanses, given a category.
     * @return  a fresh ArrayList containing the category elements, or null if the category does not exists
     */
    public List<Item> getItems(String category) {
        List<Item> list = this.expanses.get(category);
        if (list == null)
            return null;
        return new ArrayList<Item>(list);
    }

    /** Get the expanses, given a category.
     * @return  a fresh ArrayList containing all the elements
     */
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
        for (List<Item> l: this.expanses.values()) // fill with each category items
            list.addAll(l);
        return list;
    }

    /** Get the total cost, given a category. */
    public int getCost(String category) {
        List<Item> list = this.expanses.get(category);
        if (list == null)
            return -1;
        int cost = 0;
        for (Item item: list)
            cost += item.cost;
        return cost;
    }

    /** Get the total cost. */
    public int getCost() {
        int cost = 0;
        for (List<Item> l: this.expanses.values())
            for (Item item: l)
                cost += item.cost;
        return cost;
    }


    // lets test this structure
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Trip trip1 = new Trip();

        trip1.add("apple", 10, "food");
        trip1.add("cheese", 15, "food");
        trip1.add("hat", 30, "clothes");


        System.out.println( trip1.getItems("food") );
        System.out.println( trip1.getCost("food") );
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println( trip1.getItems() );
        System.out.println( trip1.getCost() );

    }

}
```

Comment: But if I want to make a Trip in the first activity but to add expenses in the second activity so how I do this?

Comment: and how I make an array list for all the trips because I want a list view in the first activity?

Comment: what is an activity ? do you mean a category ?

Comment: to make an array list just do `List<Trip> trips = new ArrayList<Trip>();` (make sure you understand how [Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) works)

Comment: Thank you, It works

Comment: how I make a listview with the items?

Comment: I don't know how to remove item. can you help me please?

Comment: @GuyRajwan use the documentation ! removing an item...
1) from a List: [l.remove(index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or [l.remove(item)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)
2) from a Map: [m.remove(key)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: but how I know what is the key? I have the item number from the list (with all the categories and I need his number only in his category) so how can I do this?

Comment: @GuyRajwan Keys are for Maps. Here you need [list_cat.remove(item)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) I suppose ? You can get the item from the *index* (what you call *number*) with [list.get(item)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-). *remove(item)* finds the item index by itself, you don't need to calculate it.

Comment: Did you tried to use the documentation? You could save a lot of your time by learning to read it! It's like a dictionary you know, you don't need to read and know every single word of it, just learn to find what you need (functions names are pretty explicits).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some classes

```
class Trip {
    private ArrayList[Category] categories = new ArrayList();

    public void addCategory(Category c) {
         categories.add(c);
    }
    public void getCategory(int index) {
         categories.get(index);
    }
}

class Category {
    private ArrayList[Expense] expenses = new ArrayList();

    public void addExpense(Expense e) {
         expenses.add(e);
    }
}


class Expense {
    private String name;
    private int amount;

    public Expense(name, amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

And then in the other parts of your code you can do things like

```
Trip africa = new Trip();
africa.addCategory(new Category());
africa.getCategory(0).addExpense(new Expense("apple", 10));
```

You might want your `ArrayList` of categories inside `Trip` to be a `HashList`, then your categories can have names.

Comment: by `put`, you mean `add` ?

Comment: But I want that the user pick a name. so I make edit text and string, the string equals to etNewTrip.getText().toString().
Trip string = new Trip();
But I get an error, "Variable is already defined in the scope" so how I fix it?

Comment: That error means that you have already defined the variable `string` in your code. You need to use different name.

Comment: So I want to add a category but in other activity so how I do this?

Comment: If you want to save the data, you will need to have a real database, google for "android sqlite". You can find a lot of tutorials about this kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

try to make a trip an object(with those values associated with it) then put that into a list instead of making so many lists